# How to access weight of a paragraph in twig?

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I use paragraphs with my content type. I need to show weight (order) value of each paragraph in my twig template. I can change weight with select box when I edit the node, but I can't figure out how to get it in twig.

I thought it would be something like this:

```
function ws_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) 
{
    $par = $variables['paragraph'];
    $myweight = $par->weight;
}
```

Please help)

Comment: The weight you change in the node edit form is not stored anywhere. It is used to rearrange the items of a multi value field (not only for paragraphs)  and renumber the deltas of the field.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to get this deltas and calculate the weights?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but you find the deltas in the field, not the referenced paragraphs.

Comment: The aim of all this to show order number of paragraphs 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 in paragraph twig template. May be some other way?

Comment: Use `{{ loop.index0 }}` in a field template like `field--field-paragraph.html.twig`

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for the answer in the wrong direction. I rendered paragraph fields in field-- .html.twig and it becomes really easy task)) Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The weight of a paragraph is not stored in the paragraph itself, but in the host field.

So if you need to get the weight of a paragraph from within the paragraph (e.g. from  within `hook_preprocess_paragraph()`), you have to go upwards to the parent entity and find your the weight there:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
  $parent = $paragraph->getParentEntity();
  // get all paragraph IDs sorted by weight
  $weights = array_map( function($a) {return $a['target_id'];}, $parent->get($paragraph->get('parent_field_name')->value)->getValue());
  // find the weight of my paragraph ID
  $weight = array_search($paragraph->id(), $weights);
  // ...do stuff with $weight... e.g. assign it to a Twig variable
  // $variables['weight'] = $weight;
}
```

Please note that the weight is easier to get if you use the paragraph host field template instead (see @4k4's comment below the original question):

> Use {{ loop.index0 }} in a field template like
> field--field-paragraph.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorting fields in paragraph template (paragraph.html.twig) in a next way:

```
{% set items = content|sort((a, b) => a['#weight'] <=> b['#weight']) %}
```

Note: that there could be "odd" fields like "_layout_builder", so to avoid rendering items without weight just use condition:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if item['#weight'] is defined %}
    {{ item }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll find it here for its fields:

```
$variables['content']['FIELD_NAME']['#weight'];
```

and then again in every item of a field:

```
$variables['content']['FIELD_NAME'][0]['#weight'];
$variables['content']['FIELD_NAME'][1]['#weight'];
$variables['content']['FIELD_NAME'][2]['#weight'];
$variables['content']['FIELD_NAME'][..]['#weight'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not working. $variables['content'] doesn't have #weigth key and $par->getDisplayOptions('view') displays error Call to undefined method Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::getDisplayOptions()

Comment: Sorry .. answered to quick and without verification of the code ;) Updated!